# Get Instagram UserId from Username? (Without API)

Tags: php, instagram

Is there a way to convert Instagram *Username* to *UserId* without using the official API?

#### I tried:

```
https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1
```

I was not able to extract data from it. And, when I tried putting it in PHP File and getting var_dump...

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/myusername/?__a=1'));
```

I got bool(false) in output.

Is there a way to do so without using the official API?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/myusername/?__a=1');
$response = json_decode($response);
$userId = $response->graphql->user->fbid;
var_dump($userId);
```

Comment: thanks for answer , i try your code and it return NULL in output